# Closed ResultSet without closing statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

In my application, the following code

```
ResultSet images = statement.executeQuery("SELECT id, filename, run" +
          " FROM images" +
          " JOIN comparer_results results ON results.toImageId = images.id" +
          " WHERE result <= 100");

while (images.next()) {
    statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = "
        + images.getInt("id"));

    File imageFile = new File(config.getProperty("system.imageDirectory")
        + File.separator
        + images.getString("filename") + ".jpg");
}
```

Throws the exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
```

In the line where the `imageFile` get instantiated. It's my understanding that this is caused by the `images.getString("filename")` operation. But why is the ResultSet closed? I never call such a method and the first operation on the resultset (`images.getInt("id")`) works just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assoon as you called

```
statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM images WHERE id = "
    + images.getInt("id"));
```

you re-used the `statement`. This means that any previously created `ResultSet` is closed automatically.

You must use two `Statement`s in this case.